# Split Text Name String in HTML After Page is Rendered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that is rendering multiple names from a data source. The names render as below:

```
Jones, TomSmith, JohnBrown, Mary
```

For the values: `Jones, Tom - Smith, John - Brown, Mary`

The `HTML` is as shown below:

`<td>Jones, TomSmith, JohnBrown, Mary</td>`

I want to break up the output so it looks like this:

```
Jones, Tom - Smith, John - Brown, Mary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and string replacement for this.

Assuming you have your string in some variable `a`.

```js
let a = "Jones, TomSmith, JohnBrown, Mary;
let b = a.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)/g, "$1 - $2";
console.log(b);
```

Will output:

> "Jones, Tom-Smith, John-Brown, Mary"

How's that? We match an upper case letter followed by any number of lower case letters twice and insert " - " between these matches. The regex `([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)` might be more accurate, requiring at least one lower case letter after the upper case ones.

---

In case you don't know how to get the names from the mark-up or write back to it.

```js
let e = document.querySelector("td"); // you'll have to select the right element here
let a = e.innerText;
let b = a.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)/g, "$1 - $2";
e.innerText = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to replace every uppercase letter "`$`" by the "`- $`" only if the previous letter is lowercase. We can use the [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for this:

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test");

test.innerText = test.innerText.replace(/[A-Z]/g, (m, idx, s) =>
{
    return s[idx-1] && /[a-z]/.test(s[idx-1]) ? ` - ${m}` : m;
});
```

```html
<p id="test">Jones, TomSmith, JohnBrown, Mary</p>
```

Other possible solution is to replace the pattern `<lowercase_letter><uppercase_leter>` by `<lowercase_letter> - <uppercase_leter>`:

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test");
test.innerText = test.innerText.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 - $2");
```

```html
<p id="test">Jones, TomSmith, JohnBrown, Mary</p>
```